# BASE SAS: Assigning values based on values in other rows

Tags: sas

I'm trying to assign values based on values in other rows. Having trouble with syntax - not sure where to start.  Below are two data sets one in what I start with and the other is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Here is my criteria/logic:

I have to assign correct Placement_tactic to Adddnames.

If Placement_tactic is missing and AddType is =Default

1. Then need to look at Placement_Type
2. Find Placement_Type in other rows
3. If Placement_Tactic is populated
4. Then set placement_tactic to the same as Placement_Type

This is what I start with, notice the missing values in Placement_tactic:

```
data have;
  infile cards missover;
  input AddNAme $16. AddType $9.  Placement_Type $34. Placement_tactic $16. ;
cards; 
160x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_DMP_COM_RT_CPM     
160x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_DMP_COM_RT_CPM     
160x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_DMP_COM_RT_CPM     
160x600DefaultAd Default  AD.COM_1H_BAU_ACQ_C2C_BAU_DISPLAY 
160x600DefaultAd Default  AD.COM_1H_BAU_ACQ_C2C_BAU_DISPLAY 
160x600DefaultAd Default  AD.COM_1H_BAU_ACQ_C2C_BAU_DISPLAY 
300x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_MLP_CPM    
300x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_MLP_CPM    
300x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_MLP_CPM    
300x600DefaultAd Default  ROCKET_FUEL_1H    
300x600DefaultAd Default  ROCKET_FUEL_1H    
300x600DefaultAd Default  ROCKET_FUEL_1H    
RedAdd100        standard AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_DMP_COM_RT_CPM     Acquisition
RedAdd100        standard AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_DMP_COM_RT_CPM     Acquisition
BlueAdd100       standard AD.COM_1H_BAU_ACQ_C2C_BAU_DISPLAY Moblie
BlueAdd100       standard AD.COM_1H_BAU_ACQ_C2C_BAU_DISPLAY Moblie
SaleAd           standard AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_MLP_CPM            Remarketing
SaleAd           standard AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_MLP_CPM            Remarketing
SaleAd           standard ROCKET_FUEL_1H                    PreRoll
SaleAd           standard ROCKET_FUEL_1H                    PreRoll
;
```

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
data WANT;
  infile cards missover;
  input AddNAme $16. AddType $9.  Placement_Type $34. Placement_tactic $16. ;
cards; 
160x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_DMP_COM_RT_CPM     Acquisition     
160x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_DMP_COM_RT_CPM     Acquisition     
160x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_DMP_COM_RT_CPM     Acquisition 
160x600DefaultAd Default  AD.COM_1H_BAU_ACQ_C2C_BAU_DISPLAY Moblie  
160x600DefaultAd Default  AD.COM_1H_BAU_ACQ_C2C_BAU_DISPLAY Moblie  
160x600DefaultAd Default  AD.COM_1H_BAU_ACQ_C2C_BAU_DISPLAY Moblie  
300x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_MLP_CPM            Remarketing     
300x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_MLP_CPM            Remarketing
300x600DefaultAd Default  AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_MLP_CPM            Remarketing
300x600DefaultAd Default  ROCKET_FUEL_1H                    PreRoll 
300x600DefaultAd Default  ROCKET_FUEL_1H                    PreRoll 
300x600DefaultAd Default  ROCKET_FUEL_1H                    PreRoll 
RedAdd100        standard AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_DMP_COM_RT_CPM     Acquisition
RedAdd100        standard AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_DMP_COM_RT_CPM     Acquisition
BlueAdd100       standard AD.COM_1H_BAU_ACQ_C2C_BAU_DISPLAY Moblie
BlueAdd100       standard AD.COM_1H_BAU_ACQ_C2C_BAU_DISPLAY Moblie
SaleAd           standard AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_MLP_CPM            Remarketing
SaleAd           standard AOD_1H_BAU_ACQ_MLP_CPM            Remarketing
SaleAd           standard ROCKET_FUEL_1H                    PreRoll
SaleAd           standard ROCKET_FUEL_1H                    PreRoll
;
```

Answer (score 1):

The "full story" of your data is not clear - if it's possible that `Placement_tactic` can be missing and `AddType ^= Default` at the same time, if it's possible that there's no populated `Placement_tactic` for a certain `Placement_type`, if there can be  other `AddTypes` with missing `Placement_tactic` etc etc.

So far it looks like you just want to expand populated `Placement_tactic` values for a certain `Placement_type` to non-populated rows. It can be easily achieved with sorting and then retaining first value in DATA-step:

```
proc sort data=have ; by Placement_Type descending Placement_Tactic; run;
data want;
     set have;
     retain _tactic;
     by Placement_Type;
     if FIRST.Placement_Type then _tactic=Placement_Tactic;
     else Placement_Tactic=_tactic;
     drop _:;
run;
```

It works for the sample data provided.

Comment: This is helpful. Yes, placement tactic can be missing but I am only concerned with coding when is default. I do this recode after I code all the other observations are coded. The PT values for default observations are based off of what was previously re coded. Not sure how to midify the program.

Comment: I oly want to code the observations with a 'default' value in addtyope but if Placement_Tactic is something other than default then leave the way it if but a default observation has then same Placement_Type as a non default observation then it is coded with that PT